# How to convert multiple tuples into a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, xml, list, pandas, data-science

I have a for loop i wrote that returns multiple tuples like this from an XML file. It looks something like this:

```
(a, b, c)
(a, b, c)
(a, b, c)
(a, b, c)
........
```

The XML file is such that a, b & c are under the same child tag. And, each of all as, bs,and cs are the same datatype. I tried getting each added to an empty list z= [], with the z.append(yyy) in the same nested for loop, i kept getting something like this:

```
[(a, b, c), (a, b, c)] 
[(a, b, c)]
[(a, b, c), (a, b, c) ... ]
........
```

I understand why it is like that because probably each list is is tied to same child tag in the XML tree. However, what i wanted was just to have a list of tuples like this:

```
[(a, b, c), (a, b, c), (a, b, c), (a, b, c), ....]
```

to enable me convert that to a Pandas DataFrame. What is the best way to do that? Is there a way to do that directly from the tuples without making up a list? Thank you.
Snippet of my code is thus:

```
for x in root.findall('xyz'):
    y = x.abc[-1]
    z = []
    for s in x.iter('xxx'):
        yyy = s.text, s.attrib['zzz'], y
        z.append(yyy)
    print(z)
```

Note: abc is a child element of xyz, and xxx is another child element of xyz. zzz is an attribute in the xxx element tag. Also note that xxx varies in that document: meaning you could have more than one under the xyz element.

The XML looks something like this:

```
<root>
    <xyz>
       <abc>...</abc>
       <abc>...</abc>
       <abc>c</abc>
       <xxx zzz='b'>a</xxx>
    </xyz>
    <xyz>
       <abc>...</abc>
       <abc>...</abc>
       <abc>c</abc>
       <xxx zzz='b'>a</xxx>
       <xxx zzz='b'>a</xxx>
    </xyz>
    ......
 </root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, what i wanted was just to have a list of tuples like this:
>
> [(a, b, c), (a, b, c), (a, b, c), (a, b, c), ....]

In order to get all the tuples in one list, you must initialize the empty list z outside of alls loops:

```
z = []
for x in root.findall('xyz'):
    y = x.findall('abc')[-1]
    for s in x.iter('xxx'):
        yyy = s.text, s.attrib['zzz'], y.text
        z.append(yyy)

print(z)
```

From there you should be able to easily convert your data into a pandas dataframe. Good luck!

Comment: Hmmm, it didn't occur to me that i didn't have that, because ordinarily for loops are initialized like we have in C++ and Java. Hope i can get up to speed with Python pretty quick. Thanks @MathiasL for pointing me in the right direction.